# ModelAdmin Customization of Searchable fields

Tags: php, silverstripe

I got a many to many relationship between Products and Categories using Silverstripes' ORM. All is working except when I try to add a Category for a product the choices for Category is shown by user id instead of Category name.  I tried to map ID to name but did not work. Below is what I tried, what am I missing?

```
class Product extends DataObject {

  private static $db = array(
    'ProductName' => 'Varchar(32)',
    );

  private static $many_many = array (
    'Category' => 'Category'
  );
}


class Category extends DataObject {

  private static $db = array(
    'Category' => 'Varchar(32)',
    );

  public function searchableFields() {
    return array (
      'Category' => array (
        'filter' => 'ExactMatchFilter',
        'title' => 'Category',
        'field' => 'TextField'->setSource(
                        $this::get()->map('ID','Category')
                    )
      )   
    );
  }

  private static $belongs_many_many = array (
    'Product' => 'Product'
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Silverstripe needs to display a shorthand for a DataObject, it will call the [getTitle()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-DataObject.html#_getTitle) method on that DataObject.

`getTitle()` will first check if the DataObject has a `Title` field and return that value if it does.

If your DataObject doesn't have `Title` field, it will try searching for a `Name` field.

If it can't find a `Name` field either, it will default to returning the ID of your DataObject, which is probably what is happening for you.

**How to fix your specific example**

There's 2 ways you can fix your specific example:

1. Rename your DataObjects DB fields to `Name` or `Title`
2. Override the `getTitle()` method on your 2 DataObjects

**Solution #1**

```
class Product extends DataObject {

  private static $db = array(
    'Name' => 'Varchar(32)',
    );

  private static $many_many = array (
    'Category' => 'Category'
  );
}


class Category extends DataObject {

  private static $db = array(
    'Name' => 'Varchar(32)',
    );

  public function searchableFields() {
    return array (
      'Category' => array (
        'filter' => 'ExactMatchFilter',
        'title' => 'Category',
        'field' => 'TextField'->setSource(
                        $this::get()->map('ID','Category')
                    )
      )   
    );
  }

  private static $belongs_many_many = array (
    'Product' => 'Product'
  );
}
```

**Solution #2**

```
class Product extends DataObject {

  private static $db = array(
    'ProductName' => 'Varchar(32)',
    );

  private static $many_many = array (
    'Category' => 'Category'   );

  public function getTitle() {
    return $this->ProductName;   
  }
}


class Category extends DataObject {

  private static $db = array(
    'Category' => 'Varchar(32)',
    );

  public function searchableFields() {
    return array (
      'Category' => array (
        'filter' => 'ExactMatchFilter',
        'title' => 'Category',
        'field' => 'TextField'->setSource(
                        $this::get()->map('ID','Category')
                    )
      )   
    );   }

  private static $belongs_many_many = array (
    'Product' => 'Product'   );

  public function getTitle() {
    return $this->Category;
  }

}
```

**Which solution is best?**

In your specific case, I would go with solution #1, because your DB fields  are functionally name/title fields.

I would use solution #2 if my DataObject's title needs to use many fields. Let's say you a have `Person` DataObject with a first name and a last name:

```
public function getTitle() {
  return $this->FirstName . ' ' . $this->LastName;
}
```